# How to pass generated data from a Auth Middleware to a Blueprint function in Flask 2?

Tags: python, flask, middleware, blueprint

I have a function `foo()` defined from a Blueprint and from it I need to be able to read
to a variable that is only created a moment before when the Middleware is executed.

I have something like this:

`app.py`

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    with app.app_context():
        app.register_blueprint(my_blueprint)
        app.wsgi_app = MiddlewareExample(app.wsgi_app)
        return app
```

`my_middleware.py`

```
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response

class MiddlewareExample:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)
        headers = request.headers

        ...

        result_validation = some_validations(headers)
        my_data = result_validation['some_result']

        if my_data['some_error']:
            ...
            # return error response


        # If the validation is success i'll need `my_data` later on foo()
        # somehow pass `my_data` to the Blueprint

        ...

        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

```
my_custom_blueprint.py
```

```
demo_routes = Blueprint('demo', __name__, url_prefix='/demo')


@demo_routes.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def foo():
    # do something with the previously generated `my_data` variable
```

I could use `current_app.config['my_data']` from the blueprint side having used `self.app.config` from the middleware, but the data I need to pass to the blueprint will be generated from a validation that I need to always apply to almost every route in my app, the content of `my_data` will be different with each request and using "app.config" might not seem like such a good idea if I will have hundreds of requests.

I even tried to pass it somehow through the header but if it is possible I did not discover it :(

In some places I saw data being added to `environ['my_data'] = 'hello'`, I didn't figure out how to read `environ` from the Blueprint, however I think it would be something similar to using `app.config`.

It is possible to do something like this by going through the middleware without using a session or storing the information in database?

If there is an answer that can bring me closer to this result that I need, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs to do something similar to what I needed,
Here's an example of how I ended up solving it using a decorator.

```
def my_custom_validator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        headers = request.headers

        result_validation = some_validations(headers)
        my_data = result_validation['some_result']

        return f(*args, **kwargs, my_data=my_data)  # <-- from here I can attach it to the blueprint
    return decorated_function
```

On the blueprint..

```
demo_routes = Blueprint('demo', __name__, url_prefix='/demo')


@demo_routes.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@my_custom_validator
def foo(my_data):
    # Now I can manipulate my data from here
```